# Yii-Bootstrap: using a dynamic image (facebook profile) in TBMenu

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, yii

I am trying to use a facebook profile image in TBMenu - as a menu item - using Yii-Bootstrap. However instead of showing an image on the menu, I see the HTML code displayed so something like

In the code below this is the $imageUrl variable.

```
    if (Yii::app()->user->getState(isFacebook)) {
    $imageUrl = "<img src='" . Yii::app()->facebook->getProfilePicture(array('height'=>20,'width'=>20)) . "'>"; 
}
    $this->widget('bootstrap.widgets.TbNavbar',array(
    'brand'=>"<img src='/images_static/logo.png'>",
    'brandUrl'=>array('/site/index'),
    'brandOptions'=> '', 
    'type'=>'',
    'fluid'=>false,
    'collapse'=>true,
    'items'=>array(
        array(
            'class'=>'bootstrap.widgets.TbMenu',
            'items'=>array(
                array('label'=>'Annonces', 'items'=>array(
                    array('label'=>'Déposer une annonce', 'url'=>array('/annonce/create')),
                    array('label'=>'Voir les annonces', 'url'=>array('/annonce/index')),
                    )
                ),
                array('label'=>'Annuaire Pro', 'items'=>array(
                    array('label'=>'Référencer votre activité', 'url'=>array('/annuaire/create')),
                    array('label'=>'Voir les activités', 'url'=>array('/annuaire/index')),
                    )
                ),
            ),
        ),
        array(
            'class'=>'bootstrap.widgets.TbMenu',
            'htmlOptions'=>array('class'=>'pull-right'),
            'items'=>array(
                array('label'=>'Idenfitiez-vous', 'url'=>array('/account/login'), 'visible'=>Yii::app()->user->isGuest),
                array('label'=>'Inscrivez-vous', 'url'=>array('/account/register'), 'visible'=>Yii::app()->user->isGuest),
                array('label'=>$imageUrl, 'visible'=>Yii::app()->user->getState(isFacebook), 'items'=>array(
                        array('label'=>'Mes contenus', 'url'=>array('/account/index')),
                        array('label'=>'Se déconnecter', 'url'=>array('/account/logout')),
                        ),
                array('label'=>Yii::app()->user->name, 'visible'=>!Yii::app()->user->getState(isFacebook), 'items'=>array(
                        array('label'=>'Mes contenus', 'url'=>array('/account/index')),
                        array('label'=>'Changer mon mot de passe', 'url'=>array('/account/changepassword')),
                        array('label'=>'Se déconnecter', 'url'=>array('/account/logout')),
                        ),
                    ),
                ),
            ),
        ),
    ),
));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try to set `encodeLabel` (defaults to true) to false :

```
$this->widget('bootstrap.widgets.TbNavbar',array(
  'encodeLabel'=>false,
  .....
));
```